# Android activity transition animation for called activity only

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-animation, android-transitions

I'm attempting to create an android activity transition where activity a calls activity b, I need activity b to slide in from the right of the screen when called and slide out of the right side of the screen when destroyed, during both transitions I need activity a to stay in place and not animate whatsoever.

I've searched for this and all animations I find are making activity a animate as well as I am trying to avoid this, any help will go a long way thanks!

intent from calling activity:

```
 public void searchButtonClick(View view) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animate1, R.anim.animate2);

}
```

animate1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime" />

</set>
```

animate2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
    android:duration="700" />

</set>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @Rachit sorry about that, I updated the question above

Answer (score 0):

Add below line

```
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.animate1, R.anim.animate2);
```

in your `onStart()` or `onCreate()` of `SearchActivity.class`